# Code tag with spaces within CSS grid causes layout to break

Tags: css, css-grid

I do have a container which is displayed as grid with three children; one left (.25fr), one middle (1fr), one right (.25fr). As soon as I insert a `<code>` tag within the mid child which does have lots of whitespaces the entire layout is broken.

I've also tried to give the `pre` and/or `code` max widths / overflows, but nothing fixed it.

Anyone got an idea?

```css
.test {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.25fr 1fr 0.25fr;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.left {
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
    <pre>
      <code>                                                    ff</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="mid">mid</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3yq8re4/)

Comment: because `<pre>` tags have `white-space: pre;` (which is their purpose). You want `white-space: normal;` but then the white space won't be preserved.

Comment: Tried to change `white-space`, but that didn't fix it. Additionally I don't really get how the "dupliated question" provides an answer to my problem.